# Is there any way to rotate an MKMapView and still show the Google Logo?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

Ok, so I've seen some similar questions to this, but can't seem to find any that really answer the question so here goes.

I'm rotating (or would like to) an MKMapView:

```
[mapView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle)];
```

This works fine, except that the Google Logo gets rotated with it, which I hear is a no no. Also I would like to actually make my mapView larger than the screen so that when rotated the entire screen still shows map, but this would also move the Google Logo off the screen.

So is it possible to rotate an MkMapView and still show the Google Logo ??? Maybe a call out to some Google Web AP

Comment: Hey Fraggle, did you finally submit your app with moved logo? Did it go through? I'm in a similar situation right now, have to move Google logo, but I'm wondering whether it's worth my time to do that, or I should just use open street map straight away.

Comment: Yes, I did do it. Just make sure the Google Logo still shows in the right place. So Google Logo isn't "moved" still looks the same. The map however gets rotated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've figured out a way to do this, although I still feel its a bit of a hack because Apple could change things in future releases that will break this technique.

MKMapView has 2 subviews. One of them is a UIImageView that holds the "Google" image for copyright purposes.

So in IB you can setup your own UIImageView that sits at the lower left corner, and in code you can set its image to be the same image as the one in the UIImageView inside the map view:

```
-(void) getImage {
    for(UIView *v in mapView.subviews) {

        if([v isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
            NSLog(@"%@",v);
            self.cpyView.image=((UIImageView *)v).image;
        }
    }

}
```

Now when you rotate your MKMapView, your UIImageView won't get rotated.

Now the other trick here is to have the MKMapView embeded in another view (viewForMap) (idea borrowed from Beginning iOS 4 by Wei-Meng Lee).

Drop a UIView into IB and size it to the size you want the visible map to be. Set it to clip sub views in IB.

In code you'll alloc] initWithFrame an MKMapView so that the MKMapView sits centered on this viewForMap, but is larger than it.

For example, if your viewForMap is 320, 372, then do this:

```
mapView=[[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-90,-64,500,500)];
mapView.mapType=MKMapTypeHybrid;
mapView.delegate=self;
[viewForMap addSubview:mapView];
```

Now you can rotate your map `mapView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI/2);`

Your UIImageView that is holding the "Google" image won't get rotated so it stays visible. The "Google" image inside the MKMapView will be off screen.

Comment: Your first suggestion here is interesting in my case... In my case, I put an UIImageView on top of the map and it appears it partly covers the Google logo. I'll try with just moving the Google image itself, without adding a new one anywhere else. I'll just put it in the top left corner, adjust its frame. Hope this goes well. :-P I don't suppose anyone else tried that and got away with it?

Comment: This solution worked perfect in iPhone but it doesn't show the google logo in iPad version.

Any idea why?

Comment: @Jorge ->Keep in mind that Apple is not going to have Google Maps as their provider in iOS 6, which is coming out REALLY soon. However, to be compatible with <iOS6 you'll still need to solve that problem I guess. Anyway if I remember correctly I think I ended up saving a copy of the png Google logo and just adding that instead of dynamically extracting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

1. Make a picture "Google" logo in any image editing program.
2. Increase the size of your MKMapView, that would not have seen the logo.
3. Add a subview of your picture to MKMapView.

If you'll do without the logo of Google, your application will be rejected according to the following:

8.6 Google Maps and Google Earth images obtained via the Google Maps API can be used within an application if all brand features of the original content remain unaltered and fully visible. Apps that cover up or modify the Google logo or copyright holders identification will be rejected

And best of all, use this: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/IPhone

Comment: Right, that is certainly one approach. But I was hoping for something that maybe was provided in the framework for this purpose. When I was debugging my app I noticed that the mapView has 2 subviews, one of which has a frame size and origin that looks like it could be for the Google Logo, but I haven't dug any further yet.